# Android intent not working in action bar

Tags: java, android, xml, android-intent

I have to tried to make webview based app and I have writed a few code,but for example settings button call a function and function call a setttings activity but setttings activity won't call, anyway for example open in browser button calls browser with intent then it working,what is wrong in my code?

Cizgiroman.java

```
    package com.tirtak.cizgihaberapp;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.tirtak.cizgihaberapp.Database;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.Window;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebSettings.RenderPriority;
import android.webkit.WebSettings.TextSize;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class Cizgiroman extends Activity {

    private WebView webview;
    private String url;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cizgiroman);

        SharedPreferences ayarlariCek = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
        getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS, Window.PROGRESS_VISIBILITY_ON);
        webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        boolean jsAbility = ayarlariCek.getBoolean("js", true);
          webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(jsAbility);
          if(getIntent().getExtras() != null){
              Intent intent = getIntent();
                String action = intent.getAction();
                    Uri data = intent.getData();
                    url = data.toString();
                webview.loadUrl(url);
                }else {webview.loadUrl(getString(R.string.CizgiromanURL));}
          webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        final Activity MyActivity = this;
          webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){
              public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress){
                  //MyActivity.setTitle("Yükleniyor...");
                  MyActivity.setProgress(progress * 100);

                  if(progress == 100){}
              }
          });
          webview.getSettings().setRenderPriority(RenderPriority.HIGH);
          webview.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
          webview.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Cizgi Haber");
          int txtSize = ayarlariCek.getInt("txtSize", 3);
          switch (txtSize){
          case 1:
              webview.getSettings().setTextSize(TextSize.SMALLEST);
              break;
          case 2:
              webview.getSettings().setTextSize(TextSize.SMALLER);
              break;
          case 3:
              webview.getSettings().setTextSize(TextSize.NORMAL);
              break;
          case 4:
              webview.getSettings().setTextSize(TextSize.LARGER);
              break;
          case 5:
              webview.getSettings().setTextSize(TextSize.LARGEST);
              break;
          }
          boolean fileReach = ayarlariCek.getBoolean("fileReach", false);
          webview.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(fileReach);
          boolean zoomAbility = ayarlariCek.getBoolean("zoom", false);
          webview.getSettings().setSupportZoom(zoomAbility);
          boolean gpsAbility = ayarlariCek.getBoolean("gps", false);
          webview.getSettings().setGeolocationEnabled(gpsAbility);
          boolean windowsJsAbility = ayarlariCek.getBoolean("windowJs", false);
          webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(windowsJsAbility);
          boolean opAbility = ayarlariCek.getBoolean("picture", true);
          webview.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(opAbility);
          boolean sPAbility = ayarlariCek.getBoolean("password", false);
          webview.getSettings().setSaveFormData(sPAbility);
          webview.getSettings().setSavePassword(sPAbility);
          boolean dSAbility = ayarlariCek.getBoolean("desktop", false);
          if(dSAbility){
              webview.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
          }

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(webview.canGoBack()){
            webview.goBack();
        }else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.actionmenu, menu);
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); 
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings){
            openSettings();
    }else if (id == R.id.action_arama){
            search();
    }else if (id == R.id.action_reload){
            reload();
    }else if (id == R.id.action_openBrowser){
            openBrowser();
    }else if (id == R.id.action_share){
            share();
    }else if (id == R.id.action_savepage){
            savepage();
    }
        return true;
    }

    public void openSettings() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void search() {
        SharedPreferences ayarlariCek = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
        int searchMode = ayarlariCek.getInt("searchMod", 1);
            Intent i = new Intent(this, AppSearch.class);
            i.putExtra("site", R.string.CizgiromanURL);
            startActivity(i);
    }

    public void savepage() {
        /*SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        int urlcounter = preferences.getInt("urlcounter", 0);
        //editor.commit();
        String urlcountname;
        if(urlcounter == 0){
            urlcountname = "url0";
            editor.putString(urlcountname, webview.getUrl());
            editor.putInt("urlcounter" , 1);
            editor.commit();
        }else {
            int newurlcount = urlcounter++;
            urlcountname = "url" + newurlcount;
            editor.putString(urlcountname, webview.getUrl());
            editor.putInt("urlcounter", newurlcount);
            editor.commit();
        }*/
        String page_head = webview.getTitle();
        String page_url = webview.getUrl();
        String page_save_date = "N/A";
        String page_host = "cizgiroman";
        Database db = new Database(getApplicationContext());
        db.kitapEkle(page_head, page_url, page_save_date, page_host);//kitap ekledik
        db.close();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sayfa Başarıyla Kaydedildi.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    public void reload() {
        webview.reload();
    }

    public void openBrowser() {
        //webview.getUrl();
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(webview.getUrl()); // missing 'http://' will cause crashed
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void share() {
        Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
        ArrayList<String> content = new ArrayList<String>();
        content.add(webview.getTitle());
        content.add(webview.getUrl());
        sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, webview.getUrl() + "    " + webview.getTitle() + "    (Çizgi Haber ile Paylaşıldı)");
        startActivity(sharingIntent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Paylaşmak İçin Seçiniz"));
    }
}
```

actionbar.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.tirtak.cizgihaberapp.Cizgiroman" >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
        android:title="@string/action_arama" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_savepage"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_bookmark"
        android:title="@string/action_savedpages" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_share"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_share"
        android:title="@string/action_share"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_reload"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_autorenew"
        android:title="@string/action_reload"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_openBrowser"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_open_in_browser"
        android:title="@string/action_browser"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_setting"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"/>

</menu>
```

activity_cizgiroman.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.tirtak.cizgihaberapp.Cizgiroman" >

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What is the error in your logcat?

Comment: have you declare your class in manifest.

Comment: I have declared and logcat is empty